# Numerical noise in numpy when recovering the phase shifts of a sinewave

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, fft, numeric

When using the code snippet below, I expect the value of displacement_sim to almost exactly equal displacement however there seems to be a significant amount of numerical noise.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sig
plt.close("all")
#simulation
lambda_start = 1300e-9
lambda_end = 1350e-9
k_start = 2*np.pi / lambda_start
k_end = 2*np.pi / lambda_end
f_d = 8192.0 / 2.0**20.0
depth = 200e-6
displacement = 1e-9
records = 8192
sweep_length = 4000

k = np.linspace(k_start, k_end, sweep_length)
vib = displacement * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f_d * np.linspace(0,records - 1, records));
kk, vv = np.meshgrid(k, vib)
inter = 30000*(np.cos(2*(kk)*(depth + vv)) + 1)
plt.plot(inter[::100].T)
displacement_sim = (1325e-9 / (4*np.pi)) * np.abs(np.fft.fft(np.unwrap(np.angle(np.fft.fft(inter)[:,11]))))[64] / (4096)
```

The value calculated when I run the script is 9.654553207983893e-10. I have already tried running it with precise implementations of cosine with no luck. I expect it must be the FFT has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: "expect the value of displacement_sim (9.654553207983893e-10) to almost exactly equal displacement (1e-9)" --> What about these 2 values indicate "significant amount of numerical noise"?  They are within 4% of each other.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica We are trying to make measurements with 60+ db of dynamic range so 4% is actually quite large.